# R Data.Frame...Lots of Dots

Tags: r

Today is my first time using R in a while, so I decided to do a few exercises to see what I remember. Unfortunately, it seems I've failed to complete the most basic of tasks: creating a data frame.

Here is my code:

```
colleges <- data.frame(
  name <- c("Drexel University", "University of Pittsburgh", "Pennsylvania State University"),
  tuition <- c("$49,632", "$16,952", "$18,618")
)
```

And the output:

```
# >colleges
  name....c..Drexel.University....University.of.Pittsburgh....Pennsylvania.State.University..
1                                                                           Drexel University
2                                                                    University of Pittsburgh
3                                                               Pennsylvania State University
  tuition....c...49.632.....16.952.....18.618..
1                                       $49,632
2                                       $16,952
3                                       $18,618`
```

Why is it formatted so poorly? And what is the meaning of all those unnecessary dots?

Comment: Use `=` not `<-` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
colleges <- data.frame(
  name = c("Drexel University", "University of Pittsburgh", "Pennsylvania State University"),
  tuition = c("$49,632", "$16,952", "$18,618")
)
```

Note the use of `=` rather than `<-`. This names the parameters you are passing to data.frame and those parameter names are used as the column names. When you do an assign (`<-`) those parameters are unnamed so it deparses the expression to name it and you don't get a "pretty" name that way. For example

```
make.names(deparse(quote(tuition <- c("$49,632", "$16,952", "$18,618"))))
# [1] "tuition....c...49.632.....16.952.....18.618.."
```

Comment: Ought to use the left arrow, use code markup when referring to passing to `data.frame`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "=" in the `data.frame` call

```
colleges <- data.frame(name = c("Drexel University", "University of Pittsburgh", "Pennsylvania State University"),
                       tuition = c("$49,632", "$16,952", "$18,618"))
```